# How to create a time point from milliseconds since Unix epoch?

Tags: c++, time, c++17, c++20, c++-chrono

To create a time point for the current time, you can use: `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.

I cannot figure out, however, how to create a time point given milliseconds since the UNIX epoch?

Also, is `std::chrono::time_point` even the recommended way to represent "instants" in time? Or should `std::time_t` be preferred?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch? I personally prefer the point in time  `time_point` over the duration `time_t`

Comment: Thanks Ted. Sorry, I'm probably being stupid, but I still can't figure out how to create a time point given milliseconds  from Unix epoch using your link?

Comment: If you divide the milliseconds down to whatever `time_t` is (usually seconds), you could use [`from_time_t`](https://omegaup.com/docs/cpp/en/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t.html) to get to the `time_point`. Add the remaining milliseconds using `+` [`std::chrono::milliseconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

Comment: @Jack Move the checkmark over to HH's answer from mine, it is much better.

Comment: Have done, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easier/simpler:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{m}};
```

The above has a precision of `system_clock::precision` (`microseconds` on macOS, `nanoseconds` on Linux systems, and 1/10 `microseconds` on Windows).  You could also create a `time_point` with a precision of `milliseconds` if desired:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>
    tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{m}};
```

In C++20 this can be simplified to:

```
std::chrono::sys_time tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{m}};
```

`sys_time` is just a template type alias for the `system_clock` family of `time_point`s at any precision.  I.e. the above is the exact same type as the `milliseconds` precision `time_point` created before.

> Also, is std::chrono::time_point even the recommended way to represent "instants" in time? Or should std::time_t be preferred?

I recommend `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` over `std::time_t`:

- `time_point`'s based on `system_clock` have a well-defined epoch (in C++20) which is also a de-facto standard in C++17:  It counts time since 1970-01-01 00::00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.  This is also known as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  In contrast no C or C++ standard specifies the epoch of `time_t`, though using [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is common practice, and specified by POSIX.
- Though unspecified, `time_t` typically has a precision of `seconds`.  `system_clock::time_point` typically has a precision that is millions or billions finer than that.  The exact precision is not specified, but it is documented within the API so you can discover it at compile-time or run-time.  `system_clock::period` is the same `std::ratio` as `system_clock::time_point::period` and represents a compile-time fraction of a second from one tick to the next.
- `time_t` is typically just a 32 or 64 bit signed integral.  This has no type safety in generic code.  For example you can add two `time_t`'s and it compiles.  However adding two points in time is not logical (while subtracting them is).  The chrono library catches such logic bugs at compile-time.  Adding two `time_point`'s does not compile.  But you can add a `time_point` and any `duration`.  The logical algebra of `time_point`s and `duration`s is checked for you at compile-time.
- If you need to cover leap seconds, it is unspecified but common that `time_t` does not (typically it is [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).  With `system_clock`, [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is specified (you *know* you aren't counting leap seconds).  However in C++20 there is another chrono clock that *does* include leap seconds in its count:  [`std::chrono::utc_clock`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc).  Like all chrono clocks this clock has it's own type-safe family of `time_point`s, with its own convenience template type alias called `utc_time<Duration>`.  And you can convert between them using [`std::chrono::clock_cast`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.cast).

like this:

```
auto tp_sys = clock_cast<system_clock>(tp_utc);
```

Comment: Note that prior to [tag:C++20], "The epoch of system_clock is unspecified, but most implementations use Unix Time (i.e., time since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds)." -- but I don't know if there are any examples.  In [tag:C++20], unix time epoch is required.  Amusingly I assumed `time_t` is unix time in my (inferior) answer, so it isn't any better.

Comment: Thanks a lot Howard. This is really really helpful.

Comment: _All_ implementations of `system_clock` use [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in C++17.  That's how we were able to standardize existing practice for C++20. :-)  Though we came _really_ close to not being able to [when one major implementation announced it was going to change its epoch.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&t=54m18s)  I was able to talk them out of it.  They agreed with the stipulation that I [get the epoch standardized](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1).  They were very gracious, and I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto ms_since_epoch(std::int64_t m){
  return std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time_t{0})+std::chrono::milliseconds(m);
}
```

this returns a system clock time point.

Like most things calendar/time related, the odds this covers things like leap seconds properly is low; odds are your ms since unix epoch value might be off by them, for example.